# Shopify Help Returning Line Item Properties

Tags: ruby, shopify, shopify-api

I am having an issue retrieving the line tem properties of an order. The problem is that the code I am using is not displaying anything. 
I am able to get the order line items, but the properties of the line item (like if I have a form field name properties[SomeText] or properties[Color])

Here is a simplified version of what I am using:

```
{% for item in order.line_items %}
Sku: {{item.item.sku}}
Product Title: {{item.title}}
    {% for prop in item.properties %}
    Properties: {{ prop.first }} = {{ prop.last }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the example above, the values for Sku and Product Title are working, but I am not getting any values returned for the Properties. I know they exist because they show when I go an view an order.

So, I'm not sure what I've done incorrectly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is valid. Please double check if your `line_items` indeed have properties and it's not actually order attributes.

Comment: If I look at the XML of the order: 
```
<order>
 <line-items type="array">
  <line-item>
   <properties type="array">
    <property>
    <name></name><value></value>
    </property>
   </properties>
  </line-item>
 </line-items>
</order>
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the Order's raw XML, I noticed that instead of using `prop.first` and `prop.last`, I changed it to `prop.name` and `prop.value` and it works.

```
{% for item in order.line_items %}
Sku: {{item.item.sku}}
Product Title: {{item.title}}
    {% for prop in item.properties %}
    Properties: {{ prop.name }} = {{ prop.value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a name field on the product page.

Comment: <p class="line-item-property__field">     <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>     <input required class="required" id="full-name" type="text" name="properties[Full Name]">    </p>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).